# QML settings for combobox

Tags: qt, qml

I'm writing settings with qml `Settings`

```
Settings {
    id: powerTuneSettings
    property alias serialPortName: serialName.currentText
}
```

Saving works but when programm starts the settings gets overwriten by first entry in the model:

```
ComboBox {
    id: serialName
    width: 200
    model: Serial.portsNames              
}
```

How can I initialize the combobox with the model and set it to the stored setting?

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution is to store it as `property string` and then search for that string in the model in the `Component.onCompleted` callback of the `ComboBox`. Set `currentIndex` if found.

Comment: I tried this: `property string SerialPort: serialName.currentText` but it also overwritten on startup:

Answer (score 1):

The [`currentText`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-combobox.html#currentText-prop) property of `Combobox` is read-only, which means you cannot directly set it. To chose the current item of your Combobox, you have to set its `currentIndex`.

Instead of storing `currentText` in Settings, store the Combobox's `currentIndex` and it should work as expected.

```
ComboBox {
    id: serialName
    width: 200
    model: Serial.portsNames
}

Settings
{
    property alias currentIndex: serialName.currentIndex
}
```

Note that in order for the QML Settings to work, you may have to either set your app's organizationName or Organisation domain in your `main.cpp`

```
app.setOrganizationName("yourOrg");
app.setOrganizationDomain("domain.org");
```

Comment: I used this to save the value, combined with Velkan's answer to have a default value when no value has been set.